# Max concurrent connections to Apache Tomcat 6.0 on windows 7

Tags: tomcat, windows-7, concurrency

I have a Flex/BlazeDS application developed which is using tomcat.  This is working fine in Intranet for probably 10 users concurrently.  We are taking this application to the market where the no of users could go up to 50 or more.

Just wanted to know if I can use windows 7 as the server or do I need to get a full blown windows server.

Thanks,
Shankar.

Comment: I suspect it would be more dependant in the resources of the windows 7 machine and the resource usage of the application itself than in the operative system. Also "50 or more" is quite vague.

Comment: I have looked up in Microsoft website and it says max connections is 20 for windows 7 but it is not clear for me that it would be applicable in my case.